# Path is not moving with the nodes after linking them

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

I am new to D3 js development. I have a problem when it comes to linking the link(path) to the nodes. When moving the node, the link is not moving with them. By the way, I used d.fixed = true; in this project.

Here is the attached GIF to let you guys see what the problem is.

[image: issue]

Here is also the link from JSFiddle:
[Complete Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dondellbatac/ac0c03d0/19/#)

This is my function that is being called when dragging the link and connect on node.mouseover.

```
function connectCurrentLink(d, data, targetL, sourceL) {
  var destinationNode = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d));
  if (destinationNode.id == targetL.id || destinationNode.id == sourceL.id) {
    removeDraggableLine();
    console.log("Drag to self id ");
    return;
  }

  // check if what direction the arrow is
  var arrowFromLeft = JSON.stringify(data['left']);

  var source, target, direction;
  if (arrowFromLeft == 'true') {
    source = destinationNode;
    target = targetL;
    direction = 'left';
    console.log("arrowFromLeft = " + arrowFromLeft +
  " startingNode " + targetL.id + " destinationNode " + destinationNode.id);
  } else {
    source = sourceL;
    target = d;
    direction = 'right';
    console.log("arrowFromLeft = " + arrowFromLeft +
  " startingNode " + sourceL.id + " destinationNode " + destinationNode.id);
  }

  var link;
  link = links.filter(function(l) {
    return (l.source === source && l.target === target);
  })[0];

  if (link) {
    link[direction] = true;
  } else {
    link = {
      source: source,
      target: target,
      left: false,
      right: false
    };
    link[direction] = true;
    links.push(link);
  }

  console.log("Link " + JSON.stringify(link));

  // hide the dragged arrow after connecting
  drag_line
    .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
    .classed('hidden', true)
    .attr('d', 'M' + destinationNode.x + ',' + destinationNode.y + 'L' + destinationNode.x + ',' + destinationNode.y);

  removeDraggableLine();
}



function removeDraggableLine() {
  d3.select("path.connect").remove();
  selected_link = null;
  hasHangingLink = false;
  selected_node = null;
  isDraggingLink = false;
  isLinkTempDeletedAlready = false;
}
```